# Write or Append JSON file (nodejs)

Tags: sql, node.js, backend

I am storing Sql output in JSON file and it looks as per below

```
[{
        "SalesOrder": 17660261,
        "POnumber": "4505917837",
        "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
        "Containernumber": "GCXU5589200",
        "Sealnumber": "PZ808918",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "22/11/2022",
        "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
        "Voyagenumber": "234W",
        "Shipment1": 81775206,
        "subRows": [{
                "SalesOrder": 17915073,
                "POnumber": "4505917837",
                "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
                "Containernumber": "MRKU5967506",
                "Sealnumber": "PZ808902",
                "ETD": "01/10/2022",
                "ETA": "22/11/2022",
                "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
                "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
                "Voyagenumber": "234W",
                "Shipment1": 81775262
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here, I want to append some data on the same existing file and save the file as well.

```
[{
        "SalesOrder": 17667367,
        "POnumber": "4400098540",
        "Bookingnumber": "NAM5289673A",
        "Containernumber": "CGMU5572275",
        "Sealnumber": "6105255",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "11/10/2022",
        "Weight": 2.086916000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "DUBAI EXPRESS",
        "Voyagenumber": "0AMC1S1MA",
        "Shipment1": 81726261
    }]
```

The output should looks like as per below with comma (,) seperator,

```
[{
        "SalesOrder": 17660261,
        "POnumber": "4505917837",
        "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
        "Containernumber": "GCXU5589200",
        "Sealnumber": "PZ808918",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "22/11/2022",
        "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
        "Voyagenumber": "234W",
        "Shipment1": 81775206,
        "subRows": [{
                "SalesOrder": 17915073,
                "POnumber": "4505917837",
                "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
                "Containernumber": "MRKU5967506",
                "Sealnumber": "PZ808902",
                "ETD": "01/10/2022",
                "ETA": "22/11/2022",
                "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
                "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
                "Voyagenumber": "234W",
                "Shipment1": 81775262
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "SalesOrder": 17667367,
        "POnumber": "4400098540",
        "Bookingnumber": "NAM5289673A",
        "Containernumber": "CGMU5572275",
        "Sealnumber": "6105255",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "11/10/2022",
        "Weight": 2.086916000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "DUBAI EXPRESS",
        "Voyagenumber": "0AMC1S1MA",
        "Shipment1": 81726261
    }
]
```

I made a try using below code with fs, However its not formatting correctly as expected and moreover its a test, the 2 JSON file's are large files comprises of more than 50K rows so not sure how to achieve this?

Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated?

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('testOutput.json');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.push([{
        "SalesOrder": 17667367,
        "POnumber": "4400098540",
        "Bookingnumber": "NAM5289673A",
        "Containernumber": "CGMU5572275",
        "Sealnumber": "6105255",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "11/10/2022",
        "Weight": 2.086916000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "DUBAI EXPRESS",
        "Voyagenumber": "0AMC1S1MA",
        "Shipment1": 81726261
    }]);

fs.writeFile("testOutput.json", JSON.stringify(json))
```

Comment: seems to have an error on the push argument, it should not have a surrounded `[ ]` if you want only content

Comment: If you have performance issue, you can use the `fs.open` function to get the file handler, then read the end of the file (maybe by using the `.stat` function to define the file size) in that manner you will be able to push json record at the end + close the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data1 = [{
    "SalesOrder": 17660261,
    "POnumber": "4505917837",
    "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
    "Containernumber": "GCXU5589200",
    "Sealnumber": "PZ808918",
    "ETD": "01/10/2022",
    "ETA": "22/11/2022",
    "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
    "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
    "Voyagenumber": "234W",
    "Shipment1": 81775206,
    "subRows": [{
        "SalesOrder": 17915073,
        "POnumber": "4505917837",
        "Bookingnumber": "609148429",
        "Containernumber": "MRKU5967506",
        "Sealnumber": "PZ808902",
        "ETD": "01/10/2022",
        "ETA": "22/11/2022",
        "Weight": 2.261000000000000e+004,
        "Vesselname": "NORTHERN JUBILEE",
        "Voyagenumber": "234W",
        "Shipment1": 81775262
    }]
}];

var datatoappend = [{
    "SalesOrder": 17667367,
    "POnumber": "4400098540",
    "Bookingnumber": "NAM5289673A",
    "Containernumber": "CGMU5572275",
    "Sealnumber": "6105255",
    "ETD": "01/10/2022",
    "ETA": "11/10/2022",
    "Weight": 2.086916000000000e+004,
    "Vesselname": "DUBAI EXPRESS",
    "Voyagenumber": "0AMC1S1MA",
    "Shipment1": 81726261
}];


 data1.push(datatoappend[0])

console.log(data1)
```